# PUBG stuck at loading screen but game audio still plays

Tags: technical-issues, pubg-battlegrounds

Whenever I start up PUBG I can get into lobby with no issues and everything works fine. However when I click start, it puts me into a game but it goes to a loading screen (where it shows PLAYERUNKOWN'S BATTLEGROUNDS) and stays on that screen for a very long time. While I am stuck at the loading screen I can hear everything and even control my character, but I can't see anything. Sometimes I will be stuck on the loading screen for up to 5 minutes or longer (meaning by the time I can see I have already been dropped from the plane). Once the screen goes away the game plays as normal. Any fix?

My specs are:
GPU: GTX 950
CPU: I5-4590 3.0GHz
RAM: 8GB

[image: Loading Screen]
The Loading Screen I get stuck at.

Comment: Do you meet the system requirements?  What specs are your computer?

Comment: GTX 950
I5-4590 3.30ghz
8GB RAM
Game , when it loads , works fine but loading is only problem .

Comment: @markocelebic Whats your hard drive? If you have a slow read rate, that could be the problem

Comment: Myself and another friend are also having this problem.

Comment: Does the loading screen problem happen every time, or just the first game you play each day?

Comment: I myself have this issue randomly too since a recent update. Before I was able to run it smoothly and it's random when it happens. Normally I just reconnect.

Comment: @Codingale Mine seems to only happen the first time I play a game that day, every subsequent game loads much faster even if I close and restart the game. The problem does seem to return after my computer has been turned off and on again. This makes me think is has something to do with loading assets during initial connection to the server after which they hangout either in RAM or somewhere else for a bit.

Comment: I encounter this occasionally and just task manager close it and reload to try and get back in before landing.

Comment: I think you should supply more information about your settings. Do you play in full screen or windowed mode? Do you use Geforce experience? Lastest graphics driver and so on ....

Answer (score 1):

This is a [link](https://forums.playbattlegrounds.com/topic/9896-stuck-on-blank-loading-screen-fix/) to **PUGB** discussion form describing how to solve the stuck loading screen.

1. Go to the file directory C:\Users{UserID}\AppData\Local\TslGame\Saved\Config\WindowsNoEditor\ **(Replace UserID with your ID)**
2. Remove GameUserSettings.ini file
3. Restart Game

Answer (score 0):

The loading screen is a very common problem that is linked mostly to bad game engine optimization.

In my case, it worked after I moved the game from the external drive to an internal **SSD**, using the SteamTool.

Also, the PC specs are at the minimum threshold. You should consider minimum 16gb RAM (OS takes 3.5 from that 8) and a SSD for fast loading if you don't have.